# Changing TextBox fields on Lost Focus

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2007

I am making a database with access 2007. I have a form for the call center to enter customer info; Name, Address, Phone Number, ect.

There is a field for credit card numbers and while we are supposed to enter them as first 4 numbers and last for number ie.1234xxxxxxxx4321

I want to make sure if they do enter them in that it keeps the first and last 4 numbers but changes other characters to "x" when the field loses focus. Could anyone point me in the right direction of how to do this?

Thanks in advance for all help in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is something like this in your form code.

```
Private Sub txtCC_LostFocus()
      txtCC.Text = Left(txtCC, 4) & String(8, "x") & Right(txtCC, 4)
End Sub
```

Then what you see is what will get stored in the DB.  ie.1234xxxxxxxx4321

I'm going to assume you don't want to actually keep the whole CC# in your DB. That is a huge no-no unless you spend massive time & money to meet PCI compliance. Here's some info on PCI: http://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pcifaqs.php

Comment: Nope. I don't want it stored as this db won't be protected. This is only to ensure one doesn't get stored accidentally or by someone new and we get hit with a big fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only storing the first 4 and last 4 digits then the following works.  Modify the function validCreditCardNumber() to have whatever checks you want to apply.

```
Function validCreditCardNumber(creditCardNumber) As Boolean
    If Len(creditCardNumber) = 12 Then
        validCreditCardNumber = True
    Else
        validCreditCardNumber = False
    End If
End Function

Private Sub cbxCreditCardNumber_LostFocus()
    If validCreditCardNumber(cbxCreditCardNumber) Then
        cbxCreditCardNumber.Text = Left(cbxCreditCardNumber.Text, 4) & "xxxxxxxx" & Right(cbxCreditCardNumber.Text, 4)
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to store the entire number but only hide the digits from the screen then I think a input masks are what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is no input mask available for partial masking of a string entry.  You will need to use a custom function to change the data entered.  The best way to do this would probably be to link the field in the table to a hidden textbox.  You can then have a visible textbox apply some function to the value in the hidden textbox to change the characters to "X" in the LostFocus event of the visible textbox.  However, it's also going to have to write the data to the hidden textbox when you change it.